# AngularJS + Jasmine mock unit test $http factory of POST method

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

How I can make unit-test of $http factory, if it using post method, for example:

```js
// controller

  $scope.logOut = function (){
    logOutFactory.logOut().then(function(resp){
    });
  };


// service 

app.factory('logOutFactory', ['$http', '$q', 'CONST', function ($http, $q, CONST){
    var logoutApiUrl = CONST.URL+'logout';
    return {
        logOut: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http({
                    method: "post",
                    url: logoutApiUrl
                })
                .success(function (data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function (data) {
                deferred.reject('error in $http request');
                console.log(data, status, headers, config);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}]);

// unit test

describe("myApp", function () {
 
beforeEach(module('app'));
describe("Ctrl", function () {
    var scope, httpBackend, fakedMainResponse;


    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend, $http) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        httpBackend.expectPOST('https://url/logout').respond(200);
        $controller('Ctrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            $http: $http
        });
    }));
 
    it("success response - empty array from server", function () {
       //httpBackend.flush();
    });
});
});
```

How i can mock $http response in Jasmine test ???
I'm trying but i see an error "Error: Unexpected request: POST /url/logout
        No more request expected
"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to write a unit-test for the $http factory, but in your test, there is a $controller inside. Maybe you should separate this test to 2 unit-tests, one for the controller, one for the factory.

When you test the logOutFactory, you should create a $httpBackend for mocking the back end, and also **logOutFactory**.

```
var logOutFactory, httpBackend;
```

In the `beforeEach`, it just need to initialize these 2 variables :

```
beforeeach(inject(function($httpBackend, logOutFactory) {
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    logOutFactory = logOutFactory;
}));
```

And mock the httpBackend in the test method :

```
it("success response - empty array from server", function () {
    httpBackend.expectPOST('https://url/logout').respond(200);
    var success;
    // call logOut
    logOutFactory.logOut().then(function () {
        success = true;
    });        
    httpBackend.flush();
    // verification
    expect(succeeded).to.be.true;
});
```