# Unable to unit test $http method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a simple controller method like this

```
$scope.testMethod= function (urlPost) {
    var obj= {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: 'POST',
            data: $scope.prjObj,
            url: urlPost
        };
      if (obj!= undefined) {
           $http(obj).then(function (response) {
           console.log(respone)
          }) 
      //rest of the code
      }}
```

I am trying to test this method

```
 beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {
            $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
            var x ={
                key:'value'
            }
            $httpBackend.when("POST",'/path/to/url',x).respond(200, ["Toyota"]);
 // Rest of the code
})

it("Should check for the testMethod",function(){

        var x ={key:"value"
        }
        $httpBackend.expect('POST','/path/to/url',x).respond({ hello: 'World' });
        createController();
        scope.testMethod("pathToUrl");

        $httpBackend .flush()

    })
```

I follower [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509431/how-do-i-mock-http-in-angularjs-service-jasmine-test) ,[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42789183/how-to-mock-http-post-method-that-has-been-called-in-other-service-method-in-ja),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34730887/testing-a-service-function-post-response-with-jasmine) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482645/angularjs-jasmine-mock-unit-test-http-factory-of-post-method) & numerous online resources, but it is still throwing

```
Error: Unexpected request: [object Object] undefined
    Expected POST /path/to/url
        at $httpBackend (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1323:9)
        at ChildScope.$scope.addEditProject (testCtrl.js:9:11770)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (testCtrl-spec.js:201:15)
```

Any idea where I am making mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the `$http` & `$httpBackend`. The controller was expecting `$http` but it was injecting `$httpBackend`

Have created a new variable and & injected like this

```
$http=$injector.get("$http");
```